# maven-jaxb2-plugin maven generation sun-jaxb.episode

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I want to remove comments inside generated files through maven-jaxb2-plugin.

I tried:

```
<noFileHeader>true</noFileHeader>
```

and

```
<configuration>
  <args>
    <arg>-no-header</arg>
  </args>
</configuration>
```

It boths works for java classes, but doesn't work for sun-jaxb.episode which keeps the comment with the timestamp.

Thank you,
RoD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of the [maven-jaxb2-plugin] here.

The actual generation of episodes is [implemented in JAXB RI](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/master/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/xjc/addon/episode/PluginImpl.java). And [there does not seem](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/master/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/xjc/addon/episode/PluginImpl.java#L176) to be a way to disable it. Consider filing an issue in JAXB RI. Also consider implementing an own plugin for it (instead of the built-in plugin).